# Passbook - How to sort passes from passbook by inclusion date

Tags: ios, passbook

Apple says:

Use the passes method of the PKPassLibrary class to get all passes that your app is entitled to access. Passes are returned in an arbitrary order.

```
PKPassLibrary *passLib = [[PKPassLibrary alloc] init];
NSArray *passArray = [passLib passes];
if ([passArray count] > 0)
{
    PKPass *lastPassAdded = [passArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Pass Localized Name: %@",[lastPassAdded localizedName]);
    NSLog(@"Pass Organization Name: %@", [lastPassAdded organizationName]);
    NSLog(@"passTypeIdentifier =  %@", [lastPassAdded passTypeIdentifier]);
    NSLog(@"passSerial Number = %@",[lastPassAdded serialNumber]);
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[[passLib passWithPassTypeIdentifier:[lastPassAdded passTypeIdentifier] serialNumber:[lastPassAdded serialNumber]] passURL]];
}
```

In my code I can get all the coupons, but dont know if there is a form to sort by inclusion date of passbook